# Regarding a shortcut in eclipse to search pattern in backward direction

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a query regarding Eclipse shortcuts. Let's say I have a java class, shown below:

```
class As
{
    int i=10;
    public void test1(){
        System.out.println("test1 A");
    }
}

class Bs extends As
{
    int i=10;
    public void test1(){
        System.out.println("test1 B");
    }
}

public class Cvb 
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        As b = new Bs();
        System.out.println(b.i);
        b.test1();
    }
```

Now if I select `test1()` with my mouse and press `CTRL+K`, it will take me to the next occurrence of `test1()`, in other words it will go in incremental direction. What I am searching for is an Eclipse shortcut that will do the same in the backwards direction.

Comment: `Ctrl + Shift + l` might help you to find answer.

Answer (score 4):

Add <kbd>Shift</kbd> to the command: `Ctrl+Shift+K` will reverse-search for the current selection/search pattern.